# are we on testnet4 already, or is testnet simply down?

Tags: testnet

on popular sites such as blockr and blockexplorer, I see standard testnet addresses show up as "false" and the last transactions/blocks seem to be sending coins to a black hole(unspent, but not linked to any actual address). I transmitted a few transactions that too seem to have gone into limbo(not spendable anymore but not in the recipient wallet either: transaction seems cryptic compared to normal ones. I tried claiming coin from faucets such as thePiachu's testnet faucet, and those seem to be malfunctioning too :( 
Is this just an availability blip I ran into or is testnet3 now gone due to segwit testing etc. ?

Comment: testnet3 seems to be working and active for me.  It's possible that people are testing weird things on testnet that confuses the block explorers.